# Word or small phrase for an object owned by a customer on which you will do work

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The word or small phrase needs to fit into both of these sentences:

I've created a new job to install our product into this _______.
This ______ is owned by Joe Bloggs.

I'm creating an IT system for a company that installs products into customer's vehicles, boats, ride-on lawnmowers, garage doors and potentially houses.  I need a term that incorporates all of these "things".

I'm leaning towards "Asset", however it's a bit confusing because it's not this company's asset, but the customer or client's asset.

I could call it "ClientAsset" but I want to keep it focused on the company's point of view where it's the thing that receives the work.  So something that means the object that receives/takes/holds on to/contains/has work done, would be great!

Unfortunately I can't use the terms "Object" or "Item" on their own due to other constraints in the system.

This is a very important term in the system, as all the company's jobs detail work to be done on one of these objects.. if worst comes to worst I can use "JobObject"/"InstallationObject" or something similar to that.

Many thanks for any suggestions you can provide!

Comment: It's a pity you can't use Item, because that's what I think most native speakers would want to call it.  I totally agree about not using "Asset", which will confuse the hell out of anyone coming from an Accounting perspective. Can you use "Commission"?

Comment: you could possibly call them "targets"

Comment: If you read some "ye olde swordfighting lore", the two terms are agents and **patients**.  (yes, I only know this from reading *Seven Eves*!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my line of work we would assign the label Work_Package or WorkPackage with the understanding that deliverables are applied to said package. So for instance, if the job was to install two new treadmills in a Gym, then:

WorkPackage: Harvey's Gym
Deliverables: Treadmills x 2

Will requires some education as to the definition for colleagues though.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider ***workpiece*** to emphasize that it is a thing that will be worked on.

> The object which is worked on with a machine or tool. *[OED]*

Answer (score 1):

How about [**chattel**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chattel)?

From Oxford:

> 1.1 *Law* An item of property other than freehold land, including tangible goods ( chattels personal) and leasehold interests ( chattels real).
>
> 1. (In general use) a personal possession.

---

This isn't a common word with other senses that could be confused with variables in your program. Also, this can be used in the singular form, unlike most synonyms for personal *effects*.

You could call it JobChattel if you like.

Comment: It definitely isn't a common word, this is the first time I've heard of it. But it fits the context perfectly (IMO) :-).

Comment: Huh?  It's a completely common word.